# Not processed pool of transactions

Tags: transactions

Can I see a not processed pool of transactions?
I want to see my transaction in line, how many transactions before and other interesting unknown for me information. :)

As I understand transaction to include in a block when the queue will coming. Of course, we have to remember about gas prise what we use in a transaction.

Can I see that list anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to browse is called mempool. You get the list of pending transactions from your Ethereum node JSON-RPC API.

The [Ethereum transaction life cycle is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65830983/how-sending-transactions-and-receiving-events-work-in-backends-in-ethereum-block/65842575#65842575).